# Parameterizing router links with properties from the context component?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, typescript

In [this stackblitz this link works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duwvgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html):

```
<a routerLink="hello/{{name}}" routerLinkActive="active">hello</a>
```

It just shows the hello component with `Angular` as the name passed via the `ActiveRoute`.

Is it possible to parameterize the `name` property via the routerlink?  Something like (I tried this in the stackblitz but it's commented out):

```
<a [routerLink]="['hello', {{name}}]" routerLinkActive="active">hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to interpolate `name`, just use this:

`<a [routerLink]="['hello', name]" routerLinkActive="active">hello</a>`

Here is a StackBlitz demoing this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duwvgs

Comment: AH - That's what I thought, but it was not working when I had stackblitz in editor mode. Opening it in a new window caused the link to work.  Thanks.

Comment: your SB was sort of messed up. Here is one in which it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duwvgs. (note I removed the child route, but that was just to simplify things)